# Library libusb 1.0.9 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, libusb

I am having a problem with compilation of my Java file.

I want to use the `libusb-1.0.9` library, but the problem is that it cannot find the symbols, like `LibUsbException`, `LibUsb.bulkTransfer`, etc. The code is written in the [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) text editor, and I have no idea how to implement this library to my code.

Comment: Have you tried installing the libusb-1.0.9?

Comment: yes, I downloaded it and then install and everything was ok, but I always have problems with compilation

Comment: Can you post a code snippet?

Comment: it is code from this page:
http://www.mets-blog.com/java-usb-communication-usb4java/